# Unix_timestamp in Apache Hive

Tags: java, date, time, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to convert a string date "Sat Jan 25 00:13:31 +0000 2014"
to Unix Timestap using unix_timestamp() HiveQL function.

> Convert time string with given pattern to Unix time stamp (in seconds),
> return 0 if fail: unix_timestamp('2009-03-20', 'yyyy-MM-dd') = 1237532400
>
> Java Doc
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month

unix_timestamp("Jan-2014","MMM-yyyy") in Hive returns NULL

The function seems to work only with months expressed with an integer (ie MM).
Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems incredible but with other months except January (Jan) it works...

```
unix_timestamp('Feb 1 18:41:57 +0000 2014','MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy')
==> 1391280117
```

the EEE pattern for day of week doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was the localization of my linux System.

Answer (score 0):

## Using java.time

On the Java side, parse using java.time classes. The [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents, well, a year and a month.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM-yyyy" );
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "Jan-2014" , f );
```

We can get the first day of the month from that, to get a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate today = ym.atDay( 1 );
```

If you want a date-only value for Hive, you feed a string in standard SQL format. For a date-only value, SQL format coincides with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing or generating strings.

```
String output = today.toString(); // YYYY-MM-DD format per ISO 8601 standard.
```

From there you apparently want a date-time value. We can arbitrarily assign the first moment of the day. The meaning of a date and determining the first moment depends on a time zone. For any given moment, the date and time-of-day vary around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( z );
```

From that you can generate a number of whole seconds since the epoch of beginning of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`) to feed to Hive.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = zdt.toEpochSecond();
```

> 1388534400

Going the other direction, you will need to go through the `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_388_534_400L );
```

Apply a time zone if you want to view the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) of some region.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).